# Find items for which the price has changed the most number of times

Tags: sql, window-functions, presto

I have a Presto table as show below:

| Item | Price | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 25.96 | 20/11/2022 |
| B | 11.89 | 21/11/2022 |
| B | 11.89 | 22/11/2022 |
| A | 26.67 | 23/11/2022 |
| A | 26.45 | 24/11/2022 |
| B | 11.75 | 25/11/2022 |
| A | 26.45 | 26/11/2022 |

The table has 3 fields. One represents the item field and the other represents the price field whereas the last one is the date when the price was obtained.

What I would like to find out is how many times the prices have changed for an item and order them in descending order.

In the example above, the result I would like to obtain is:

A -> 3

B -> 2

From the documentation I have gone through, it looks like I need to make use of Window function to know the previous fetch price for every fetch and then compare.

Since I am new to these kinds of functions, I was unable to find the right solution. Can someone help me with the expected query here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need a date column to make sure of row orders :

```
with cte as (
select 
  item
 , case when Price = lag(Price,1,price) over (partition by item order by date) then 0 else 1 end as price_Change
from tablename 
) 

select item , sum(price_change) as price_change
from cte 
group by item
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I have updated my table with the date field in the description above. A follow up query I have is around the two separate queries shared by you above. Have you separated them out to better manage resources?

Comment: I used à cte for better readability and clear code